# Is Open GL implementation differs for differnet manufacturers?

Tags: opengl

Is only Open GL's interface common and implementations of them differs from one device manufacturer to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the general idea of how it's supposed to work out.

Comment: As a side note, device manufacturers can add their own functions (augment the OpenGL interface) through so-called extensions : www.opengl.org/registry/

Answer (score 0):

Remember that opengl isn't an API. OpenGL is an specification and each manufacturer implementents their API

Comment: I think Open GL is an API, as I checked it from this site:http://www.opengl.org/documentation/. But I think, we can also call it as an interface and each manufacturer can have their own implementation.

Comment: @Krishnan OpenGL is an specification. A "comitee" (in this case is Khronos) specifies the name of each function and the expected behaviour. Then, each hardware manufacturer implements the way that each function does the work. When the manufacturer (say Nvidia) releases their driver, then this becomes actually an API (at this moment the language is speaking with the driver).